# How to check boolean value in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, boolean-logic

In my Android application, there are two types of logins. Users can login with Facebook or Google+. When a user logs in successfully, it displays data from that particular social account. For example, when a user logs in with Facebook, it will then display data from Facebook. I've included my code:

```
demo.java

boolean isFacebook;

  if (!isFacebook) {
        txtName.setText(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(WelcomeScreenActivity.this).firstname);
        txtEmail.setText(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(WelcomeScreenActivity.this).email);

        // fetching facebook's profile picture
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                URL imageURL = null;
                try {
                    imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.facebookID + "/picture?type=small");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }.execute();

    } else {
        isFacebook = false;
         SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         String username = pref.getString("PROFILE_USERNAME", "");
         String email = pref.getString("PROFILE_EMAIL_GOOGLE", "");
         pref.getString("PROFILE_IMAGE_USER", "");
         txtName.setText(username);
         txtEmail.setText(email);
    }
 }
```

In this code, when a user logs in with Facebook, it displays Google+ detail instead.  How can I correct this?

Comment: I don't see a question in your post... So what are you asking for actually?

Comment: possible reading: http://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html

Comment: You should be able to split this into lots of smaller tests to see what isn't working.

Comment: is it solved or not?

Comment: No @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 5):

Your condition is wrong

it must be like this

```
if (!isFacebook) {
    // do false logic here you need to check for GOOGLE
}

// do true logic here you need to check for FB
```

Comment: I will try your solution but when user click on login with google+ then data display but when user login with Facebook then could not get data please help me. @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan

Comment: why you adding isFacebook = false; and isFacebook = true;

Comment: sorry for edit but I don't understand concept for true false. @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 3):

Well you're literally doing the opposite of what you described. You're fetching data from Facebook if `isFacebook` is `false`, meaning that it is NOT facebook.

Change the first if statement to `if (isFacebook)`

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead (Just got a minor mistake)

```
  boolean isFacebook;
      if (isFacebook) {
            txtName.setText(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(WelcomeScreenActivity.this).firstname);
            txtEmail.setText(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(WelcomeScreenActivity.this).email);

            // fetching facebook's profile picture
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    URL imageURL = null;
                    try {
                        imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.facebookID + "/picture?type=small");
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            }.execute();

        } else {
            //get google + details here
        }
     }
```

but this code you provided doesn't seem to collect any data from google+ in first place

also there may be a problem on the button click

```
bt_fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
isFacebook= true;`

}

bt_twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
isFacebook= false;`

}
```

and also better if you intialize the isFacebook  as   `boolean isFacebook= true;`